# What is the difference between passing values by dictionary and List in queries using cx_Oracle with python?

Tags: python, oracle

The following query is working fine (passing values by dictionary)

```
cursor.execute("""insert into MDP_ERR_MASTER (MARKERID, FILENAME, ERRORCODE, USERID, CHECKEDBY, CHECKEDDT, STATUS, COMMENTS, X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2, RECNO, PROJECT_CODE, SRC_ACC_NUM, WORKAREA, CONFIGID, ELEMENTID)
            values (:markerid,:shapename,:errcode,'0',:sysid,sysdate,'OPEN',:usercomment,:x1,:y1,0,:x2,:y2,0,1,:jobno,:srcacnum,chr(182) || :workarea || chr(182),0,0)""",
            {"markerid" : markerId,
             "shapename" : str(errorMarkerLayer.name()),
             "errcode" : errCode ,
             "sysid" : self.sysid ,
             "usercomment" : str(comments),
             "x1" : startPnt[0],
             "y1" : startPnt[1],
             "x2" : endPnt[0],
             "y2" : endPnt[1],
             "jobno" : self.jobNo,
             "srcacnum" : src_AcNum,
             "workarea" : self.wrkArea
             })
```

But below passing values by list is not working 'Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type tuple'

```
cursor.execute("""insert into MDP_ERR_MASTER (MARKERID, FILENAME, ERRORCODE, USERID, CHECKEDBY, CHECKEDDT, STATUS, COMMENTS, X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2, RECNO, PROJECT_CODE, SRC_ACC_NUM, WORKAREA, CONFIGID, ELEMENTID)
            values (:1,:2,:3,'0',:4,sysdate,'OPEN',:5,:6,:7,0,:8,:9,0,1,:10,:11,chr(182) || :12 || chr(182),0,0)""",
            [(1 , markerId),
             (2 , str(errorMarkerLayer.name())),
             (3 , errCode),
             (4 , self.sysid),
             (5 , str(comments)),
             (6 , startPnt[0]),
             (7, startPnt[1]),
             (8 , endPnt[0]),
             (9, endPnt[1]),
             (10 , self.jobNo),
             (11 , src_AcNum),
             (12 , self.wrkArea)
             ])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you provide a list, then the parameters are included in the query according to the position in the list, not by looking up a key. So, for the first value, `(1, markedId)` is being substituted instead of `markerId`.

Although a list of tuples can be easily converted to a dictionary, it is not the same data structure. Converting your parameters to a dictionary using `dict()` first will work.

```
cursor.execute("""insert into MDP_ERR_MASTER (MARKERID, FILENAME, ERRORCODE, USERID, CHECKEDBY, CHECKEDDT, STATUS, COMMENTS, X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2, RECNO, PROJECT_CODE, SRC_ACC_NUM, WORKAREA, CONFIGID, ELEMENTID)
            values (:1,:2,:3,'0',:4,sysdate,'OPEN',:5,:6,:7,0,:8,:9,0,1,:10,:11,chr(182) || :12 || chr(182),0,0)""",
            dict([(1 , markerId),
             (2 , str(errorMarkerLayer.name())),
             (3 , errCode),
             (4 , self.sysid),
             (5 , str(comments)),
             (6 , startPnt[0]),
             (7, startPnt[1]),
             (8 , endPnt[0]),
             (9, endPnt[1]),
             (10 , self.jobNo),
             (11 , src_AcNum),
             (12 , self.wrkArea)
             ]))
```

If you are using cx_Oracle, see [here](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html#Cursor.execute) for documentation.

Comment: ("insert into MDP_ERR_MASTER (MARKERID, FILENAME, ERRORCODE, USERID, CHECKEDBY, CHECKEDDT, STATUS, COMMENTS, X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2, RECNO, PROJECT_CODE, SRC_ACC_NUM, WORKAREA, CONFIGID, ELEMENTID)                values (:1,:2,:3,'0',:4,sysdate,'OPEN',:5,:6,:7,0,:8,:9,0,1,:10,:11,chr(182) || :12 || chr(182),0,0)", [(1, '1844264'), (2, 'ErrorMarker'), (3, 'J-13012_C151_00003'), (4, '3695'), (5, ''), (6, 151.9789870760234), (7, -27.427017698343075), (8, 151.9806782163743), (9, -27.42280863791423), (10, 'J-13013'), (11, 'C1133'), (12, 'Maranoa Part02_1')])

Comment: The second argument is still a list. You need to convert it to a dictionary as I said in the answer, by passing the the list of values into the dict() function.

Answer (score 0):

In the list (second code example) you still have "named" parameters.  Instead of nice names like ":markerid" you have ":1".  I believe that you must use a dictionary when using named parameters.

If you need to use the numeric named parameters, just build the dictionary with numeric key names.

If you simply need positional substitution, then I believe the "?" syntax might be supported, but I do not recommend "?" syntax because it is difficult to maintain and you have to specify identical values multiple times in the input.

Another option is to use pythons string format/replacement operator "%", which means you are taking care of the parameter substitution prior to query execution.